# How to efficiently convert array A to array B?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to manipulate array A to get array B efficiently. "k" is a given variable. I came up with the logic below, but I believe there should be better way of doing it.

***The length of the array is always dividable by k***

```
This part is not the code. It doesn't let me submit it otherwise.
k=3
Given: A = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11] 

Result: B = [9,10,11,6,7,8,3,4,5,0,1,2]

k = 4
Given: A = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]
Result: B = [12,13,14,15,8,9,10,11,4,5,6,7,0,1,2,3]
```

Given number of elements for A changes, when k changes. Number of elements for A is always k*4. If k is 2 our A array is [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7], and B array (result) should be B = [6,7,4,5,2,3,0,1]

```
let A = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]
k = 3
let B = []

    for (let i=A.length - (k-1); i >=0; i=i-k) {
        if (A.length - 1 <= i + k +1) {
            B = [
                ...B,
                ...(A.slice(i+1, i+k+1))
            ]
        }
    }
    B = [
        ...B,
        ...(A.slice(0,k))
    ]
```

Comment: perhaps you should make your code work correctly first, then worry about efficiency

Comment: Start by properly _explaining_ the logic of your transformation. Do not just drop the code with an implied “you guys go figure out what I even want here.”

Comment: To better understand what you want to achieve please post also expected result of k=1 and k=2 or k=n

Comment: Chill out people. I don't know why stackoverflow is so savage:) Sorry, I edited the question. Also, @Jaromanda, the code is working as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep it simple:

```
const A = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]
const k = 3

// assuming k >= 1 and A.length % k == 0
const B = []
for (let i=A.length; i>0; i-=k)
    B.push(...A.slice(i-k, i))
```

Comment: Yup, this was something I was looking for. I felt like my code was unnecessarily hard to read. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this is what you want?

```js
const ar=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11];

function regroup(ar,k){
  for (var r=[], i=k*~~ar.length/k; i>0 ; i-=k)
    r=r.concat(ar.slice(Math.max(i-k,0),i));
  // or, alternatively:
  for (var s=[], i=ar.length-k; i>-k ; i-=k)
    s=s.concat(ar.slice(Math.max(i,0),i+k));
  console.log("k:"+k+"\n1. version: "+r+"\n2. version: "+s)
}

for (let j=1; j<12; j++) regroup(ar,j)
```

I modified your example and set `k` to all values between  1 and 11. Your question was unclear as to what you expect to happen if the length of the array is not dividable by `k`. I assumed that you want to start with full length groups and then have the last group smaller (in this case only two elements long).

Comment: That's still as inefficient as the OPs code.

Comment: I am still in the phase of understanding what the intention of OP was ...

Comment: OP wants a "better" way to do it. I doubt that significantly more efficient ways exist than his or my approach(\*)  (basically both concatenate sub-arrays). In the end it is a matter of taste or readability. ---  (\*) In my `regroup` function I actually placed *two* versions of my concatenation approach. Only *one* is needed of course.